# Magento database repair tool throws 500 HTTP ERROR

Tags: magento-1.9, database, http-error-500, repair-tool

I'm trying to fix a Magento 1.9.3.1 database but I get the 500 HTTP ERROR everytime, after I fill in the database credentials (the corrupted database connection login details and the reference database connection login details).

I really don't understand why I get this error.... Can anyone help, please?

UPDATE: after checking the error logs, I saw this message:

> [:error] [pid 10608] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /path/to/magento/db-repair-tool.php:79

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP7 then all the `mysql_*` functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and were removed in PHP 7.0.0